# Modify User Roles in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I have been working on a client's WordPress Website and last day my client want to hide navigation menu and pages from author/contributor categories.

I have searched and tried some of the plugin but didn't get the exact thing. Please let me know what should i use to hide some pages from user and from navigation.

Only Admin can see all the pages and other members should see only 1 section that is allowed to visible for them.

Thank You

Comment: using user-role-editor plugin manage exclude admin define roll as like subscriber roll so only admin can see all details other is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> use this plugin to manage All roll:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Complete function for removing each Menu and submenu from `wp-admin` for another user:

```
function remove_menus() {
 global $menu, $submenu;
 $restricted = array(__('Dashboard'), __('Profile'), __('Users'), __('Tools'), __('Comments'), __('Settings'), __('Plugins')); //Here you can also define the name like Pages  
        end($menu);
        while (prev($menu)) {
        $value = explode(' ', $menu[key($menu)][0]);
        if (in_array($value[0] != NULL ? $value[0] : "", $restricted)) {
        unset($menu[key($menu)]);
            }
        }

    unset($menu[5]); // this is just for example
    unset($submenu['edit.php'][16]); // this is just for example


}
```

Now You have to put a conditon for other user i.e:

```
$thisusername = $current_user->user_login; // this is to get the current user login
if (($thisusername == "user123")) {
 add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menus');
}
```

**Note:** You can find many plugins but all of them are not in depth like this code.Well you can try this plugin to manage your user's roles.[Capability Manager Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/capability-manager-enhanced/)

Comment: Is there any plugin for the solution

Comment: I have provided this `.Capability Manager Plugin`  in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the plugin but that plugin's development has been stopped since 2 years :-(

Comment: I am using it.and its working fine sam.You can do lots of thing like changing the role,creating a role etc.